# Assigning json_decode values to variables

Tags: php, android, json, rest, slim

I'm developing a Restful web service for an Android app using PHP and Slim. At the moment I have been able to parse in `JSON` but I want to assign the individual values belonging to each key to variables.
So far I have being able to print out the values with `print_r($users)` but my goal is to assign each value to the following variables `$firstname`, `$lastname`, `$email`, `$password`.

Here is my `JSON`:

`{"firstname":"mishael","lastname":"harry","email":"mishharry@gmail.com","password":"godady"}`

Here is my create function

```
function createUser(){
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $body = $request->getBody();
    $users = json_decode($body);

    print_r($users);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function.

```
  $data = json_decode($body);
  extract($data);
  print $firstname;
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($users->firstname);
print_r($users->lastname);
```

or if you really want following variables $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password:

```
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}

print_r($firstname);
print_r($lastname);
...
```